# Formatting MySQL / Server timestamp with php?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have a created a timestamp in MySQL that changes when an account is updated by a users, and this timestamp is echoed on the page. However it is displaying the server time rather than my local time. I can't set the timezone in MySQL, I tried. What is another way to change this, and how can it be implemented?

Comment: you can set default timezone. like this: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');$tz = date_default_timezone_get();`

Comment: @PathikVejani Tired that before, it didn't work :)

Comment: If you actually want to alter it with PHP, you can get your current time when inserting, and convert it to timestamp (and then insert that value, of course)
You can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @Armin useful link! thanks. But how would you implement that? https://jsfiddle.net/yj5ccjmu/ and i don't need or want to alter it will php if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Actually you can probably insert it by just providing right format. For example 2016-02-09 13:31:20, which you can get like this $date =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); And try to save this value to DB? I am sorry if I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with [timestamp datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) is that

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default,
>   the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The
>   time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time
>   zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store.
>   If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and
>   retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value
>   you stored.

So, it does not really matter what your timezone setting in php is, you need to set either mysql's timezone on a session basis using

`SET time_zone = timezone`

command, or you need to store the timezone of the client along with the timestamp and adjus the value based on the stored timezone. I would use the latter approach, since a client technically can change timezones and if the client access the timestamp data from a different timezone, then different data will be returned by mysql.

Comment: Mate, did you read what he said? he said he can't set the timezone in mysql he tired that.

Comment: @AboutLeros Mate, did you read, what I wrote? I wrote **either** to set the timezone on a connection basis in mysql, **or** store the client timezone in the database. And I suggested to use the latter approach!

Comment: seriously? if they don't know the difference between "alter" and "format", do you think they will get that or be able to do it? :D

Answer (score 0):

When echoing from a database add in some "filters" seemed to do the trick

```
<?php echo $row['field name']; strtotime(date("Y-m-d", 1310571061)); ?>
```

Without the above code it displayed the timestamp as: 2016-02-09 00:00:00 
With the above code it displays thus: Tuesday, February 09, 2016

Comment: This has got nothing to do with server time or local time. This is simply formatting the same time to display it differently.

Comment: yep, no one suggested that, did they. .  so why would I change the server time if i can format what is displayed. . . and of course it has something to do with it. . . it alters it.

Comment: Just you suggested it in the question. You do not alter the time, you format it, that's a huge difference!